How to get file name of form-data request body in Postman
I cannot get file name of a file uploaded in form-data request body:

I tried: pm.request.body, it returns the request body:
{mode: "formdata", formdata: [1]}
mode: "formdata"
formdata: [1]
0: {…}
key: "file"
type: "file"
src: "/Users/errorfile.csv"

but when I tried pm.request.body.formdata.src, it returns undefined.
When I tried pm.request.body.formdata[0].src, it shows error:

"TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'src')"


The pm.request.body.formdata is data object.
So you need to convert JSON object.
Pre-request Script
const jsonData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(pm.request.body.formdata));
console.log(jsonData[0]);
console.log(jsonData[0].key);
console.log(jsonData[0].type);
console.log(jsonData[0].src);

console output
{key: "csvFile", type: "file", src: "/D:/temp/errFile.csv"}
csvFile
file
/D:/temp/errFile.csv

The JSON.parse(JSON.stringify()) technique is used to create a deep copy of an object in JavaScript.
The JSON.stringify() function converts JavaScript objects into JSON strings
JSON.parse() - This converts the JSON string back into a JavaScript object.
Once you have a deep copy of the form data, you can access its properties like any other JavaScript object.



Thank you so much @Bench Vue!
That's so brilliant. It worked. I have been struggling for days

No problem, I am happy to hear you got it. Can you accept and up vote my answer? if press up arrow in my answer, It will give me 25 points. Thanks!

I just accepted and up vote for you. Thank you again!
